# NeoVim runs part of mapping while starting

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, command-line, normal-mode, startup

I am using a Raspberry Pi for learning C. I use NeoVim and Mingw-GCC on the Pi over SSH.
Building is done with a custom script named `build`. Initial builds were done by calling `./build` from the command mode of nvim.

I want to map `Ctrl-B` to call the build script. Currently I am using this

`noremap <C-b> :w | !./build`

but everytime I run vim, it seems to be running the build script.

[image: result of running nvim on terminal]

Removing the `w |` seems to solve the problem but then I have to manually save the file before running.

I want it to just startup normally. And save before building.

Comment: See `:help map-bar`.

Comment: There isn't any help for `map-bar`

Comment: Oh yes, there is. In Vim at least.

Comment: Okay I ran vim and checked the help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The bar `|` is used to separate `{lhs}` and `{rhs}`. Thus it reads the next command as a command to run.
To use a `<bar>` in keymaps:

```
   use       works when            example  ~
   <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
   \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
   ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi     :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M
```

Comment: FWIW, text is easier to use than screenshots.

Comment: Will surely remember next time.